# How to get an object from item() method in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Everytime I try to implement a line of code given below it gives me a pointer, but on the official website of PyQt5 it says it must give me an object from a table.

A line of code that gives me a pointer instead of an object(str in this case

[image]

What might be wrong?

---

```
    self.List_Of_Tables.setRowCount(8)
    self.List_Of_Tables.setColumnCount(4)

    self.List_Of_Tables.setItem(0,0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Стол 1"))
    self.List_Of_Tables.setItem(0,1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Cola, Lays, Hookah"))
    self.List_Of_Tables.setItem(0,2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("4"))
    self.List_Of_Tables.setItem(0,3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("5000"))

    self.List_Of_Tables.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Cтолы"))
    self.List_Of_Tables.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Заказы"))
    self.List_Of_Tables.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Люди"))
    self.List_Of_Tables.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Итоговая сумма"))

    b = self.List_Of_Tables.item(0,0)
    print(b)

    if self.List_Of_Tables.item(0,0) == b:
        self.Table_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
```

Comment: Paste the entire code here. There's simply not enough data for us to see what's going on.

Comment: another part of the code is below. Thank you. Ask anything you need

Comment: Please, edit the *question*, do not create an answer. This is not a forum.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what is happening here? What is the type of `self.List_Of_Tables`? What is happening with your code? Are you getting an exception? If so, [edit] the question to include the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a QTableWidgetItem with a text and obviously that is false, the solution is to get the text of the QTableWidgetItem:

```
item = self.List_Of_Tables.item(0,0)
if item and item.text() == "Стол 1":
    self.Table_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
```